# Does "AO" in World Settings apply the GI Effect too (Cycles)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, effects, world, photorealism

When I check the **Ambient Occlusion** checkbox in the **World Settings**, the scene becomes brighter, but it also applies the AO effect.

So this is the question: **Does this option, apply both AO and GI to the scene?**

(Blender v2.82)